# Custom Keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I need a text editor for universal use and I decided that vim has the such potential. Vim is great software, but I as a new user find it difficult to get into, but I am determined to use it.
The only way I can use vim is through custom keybinds. I want to go for the windows generic keybinds since I am very used to it. I started using linux recently too. So, it a big change for me altogether.

As far as I understand vim has 3 modes command mode, insert mode and visual mode.

the key **':'** lets you enter command mode.

the key **'i'** lets you enter insert mode.

the key **'v'** lets you enter visual mode.

I want to switch **'i'** to insert append mode so that when I enter from visual mode to insert mode it start appending from where my cursor is positioned at.

In insert mode:
I want to be able to use **shift** to select text

I want to be able to use **ctrl + z** to undo

I want to be able to use **ctrl + y** to redo

I want to be able to 'save a file' in insert mode using **ctrl + s**

I want to be able to 'save a file as' in insert mode using **ctrl + shift + s**

I want to be able to use **ctrl + q** to be able to quit a file without saving

In any mode:
I want to use **ctrl + f** to find any thing in the current file content

In command mode:
I want to use **:find filename** to find any file in the current directory or in its sub directory. if a sub directory has a sub directory it should find from there too.

I want to use **":s filename or :s * name"** to be able to switch between already open files.**

There are the very basic things I want to set and if someone can help me get started with explanations I can probably start customizing my self in the future.

Comment: so you are so determined to use vim that you actually want to use notepad. If you're serious about using vim, then you need to fight the urge to change so many mappings. After a few weeks of practice, you will realize that you're quite comfortable with 98% of the design decisions that make vim a great editor.

Comment: What you're asking is a list of things you want done. This site is not for people to get free labour. It's for answering specific questions *after* OP has done proper research. What you want can be achieved quite easily (except saving with Ctrl-S, depending on whether you use terminal or GUI). Do your research.

Comment: what I think is simple. A tool is a great tool when it powers the user. Vim is a great tool and it has the ability to do so, but it would be foolish to not take advantage of the full customization and just use vim out of vi nostalgia. Heck I am was not even born at the time. So, I have no bias to old key mappings. Also I did not ask for free labor. I shared what I want done and my goals. Look at the kind fellow below who shared resources that he thought would be best to get me started. @kadekai thank you for your unhelpful comment. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It seems you’ve already gotten some advice about embracing the default key bindings rather than trying to overly customize the basics. If you still try to implement your customizations and run into trouble, feel free to ask here, but make sure you ask about a *specific* issue and show what you tried and how it failed (why it didn’t do what you wanted). For example, on the “append” behavior, give examples of how you’d like it to behave (what you mean by “append” might be different from what I understand by it.) Good luck in your Vim journey!

Answer (score 1):

so you basically want to learn something new w/o learning something new.

As someone who recently got started using nvim myself I can tell you that it is really worth it to adapt the vim way of life and really understand how and why it can provide an incredible workflow.

Those two resources helped me to get into it

- [YouTube Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3o4l4GVLW0&list=PLm323Lc7iSW_wuxqmKx_xxNtJC_hJbQ7R)
- [Quick Online "Course"](https://danielmiessler.com/study/vim/)

There is definitely a steep learning curve but you will get there!

Enjoy the journey :)

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate you sharing this. I am looking into it

Comment: I really like vimcasts, but also running `vimtutor` and then reading `:help` is a good way to get started. (Of course, no one reads these days… but I do.)

Comment: I started my self with these mappings but I still do not see a way to be able to change i binding to append mode.
 
:nmap - Display normal mode maps
:imap - Display insert mode maps
:vmap - Display visual and select mode maps
:smap - Display select mode maps
:xmap - Display visual mode maps
:cmap - Display command-line mode maps
:omap - Display operator pending mode maps

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation to you (switched from windows to linux and wanted to try vim as my editor for everything). I think you should try out the default mappings (and then build *on them* with custom ones).

The defaults are more than just a lot of shortcuts - they form a natural expressive language for editing. So if you start remapping them right away, you'll almost certainly break this language and close off large swathes of vim's power.

A couple more links to a great series of vim tutorials:

[VimCasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive/)

[Derek Wyatt](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/)